# Under the UA version of Class Feature Variants can a non-wizard use the Ritual Caster feat to copy Divination after picking the wizard's spell list?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, unearthed-arcana

At question are the following lines in the Class Feature Variants UA

> A wizard has access to the following feature.

> 1st-level wizard feature (enhances Spellcasting)
>
> The following spells expand the wizard spell list.
>
> [...]
> 4th Level
> Divination (divination, ritual)

and this text from the Ritual Caster feat

> If you come across a spell in written from, such as a magical scroll or a wizard's spellbook, you might be able to add it to your ritual book. The spell must be on the spell list for the class you chose, the spell's level must not be higher than half your level (rounded up), and it must have the ritual tag. The process of copying the spell into your ritual books takes 2 hours per level of the spells, and costs 50 gp per level of the spell. This cost represents material components spent on practicing the spell, as well as the fine inks you must use to record it.

Under the UA version of Class Feature Variants can a non-wizard use the Ritual Caster feat to copy Divination after picking the wizard's spell list?

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, this works.

The following are required to copy a spell found in written form using the [Ritual Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/ritual-caster) feat (quoted from the second bullet of Ritual Caster):

> 1. The spell must be on the spell list for the class you chose
> 2. the spell's level must not be higher than half your level (rounded up)
> 3. it must have the ritual tag

If you take the ritual caster feat at 8th level, then half your level is 4, so *divination* satisfies both (2.) and (3.) above.

As for (1.), normally [*divination*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/divination) would not appear on the wizard's spell list, but if you are using the [Class Feature Variants UA](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/class-feature-variants), *divination* does appear on the wizard's spell list - as you quoted:

> The following spells expand the wizard spell list. [...]
>
> **4th Level**
> *Divination* (divination, ritual)

Therefore, *divination* is eligible under the second bullet point of Ritual Caster if you are using the Class Feature Variants UA rules, as long as you are at least 8th level and spend the time and gold copying the spell into your ritual book.

But what about the first line:

> A Wizard has access to the following feature.

Notice - “feature” is singular. This is referring to Cantrip Versatility. *For every other class with an expanded spell list*, it says:

> A [class name] has access to the following **features**.

And every other class has more than one additional feature besides an expanded spell list.

Comment: This answer touches on most of the quoted lines except for "A wizard has access to the following feature" would a non wizard also have access to the feature indirectly? Can a player just declare the spell scroll they found is from a variant wizard and not a cleric? It is an optional feature, is the default assumption that every wizard has taken it? Etc

Comment: Surely that is a typo? Are you saying that a non-bard can't copy contact other plane from the bard expanded spell list, but a non-wizard can copy divination because the bard's say "features" but the wizard says "feature".

Comment: @kent No, he's saying that the spell list expansions aren't class features, and evidencing it via grammar.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil fair enough. That raises the question of which features in Class Feature Variants are class features but that is a separate question.